# Regex pattern in javascipt /[0-9]{7}$/

Tags: javascript, regex

how to check the string if the last 7 chars contains numbers or not using regex in java.

Comment: [0-9] <- Match any of the digits 0-9
{7} <- Has to be 7 digits in a row
$ <- These 7 digits have to be right before a newline

Comment: can you give any example string which matches that pattern.. I didn't understood what right before newline means..

Comment: sfasdofjao1234567 matches 1234567.

aspfkaspf0923523 matches 0923523.

1234567abcde0987654 only matches 0987654, because it ends right before a newline (end of line), while 1234567 doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
[0-9] = will match any digit,
{7} = the length of the digits, so the matched string will be exactly 7 digits long
$ = signifies end of line
```

so this regex will match any line that ends with 7 digits

a good way to start learning is sites like https://regex101.com/, which explain the whole regex string you input